# How to run an external program?

Tags: external, nim-lang

How to run an external program?

I want the Nim program to print the stdout output from running another program to the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

One simple way is to use the [`osproc`](https://nim-lang.org/docs/osproc.html#execProcess%2Cstring%2Cstring%2CopenArray%5Bstring%5D%2CStringTableRef%2Cset%5BProcessOption%5D) from the standard library:

```
import osproc

let result = execProcess("python", args=["-h"], options={poUsePath})
echo(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a auto-redirect output:

```
import std/osproc
const Opt: set[ProcessOption] = {
  poUsePath,
  poParentStreams
}
let p = startProcess("python", args=["-h"], options=Opt)
discard p.waitForExit()
p.close()
```